# Can a descriptors wallet be encrypted?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet

Bitcoin Core provides a builtin feature by which Berkeley DB Bitcoin Core legacy wallet files can be encrypted with a passphrase.

Can the same or similar be done to Bitcoin Core descriptors wallet files?

Comment: I'm assuming you are asking if there are instructions to be able to encrypt descriptor wallet files? I'm assuming you know that any data of any form can be encrypted?

Comment: I suspect OP is asking whether Bitcoin Core supports encrypting private keys in a wallet file, not about file-level encryption in general.

Comment: @MichaelFolkson edited :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, descriptor wallets can be encrypted using Bitcoin Core's passphrase encryption feature, just like legacy wallets.

It encrypts just the private keys, so encrypted wallets can be used normally for most purposes without access to the passphrase, but sending/signing do need it.